# error 404 al cargar pagina register y login en laravel con jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

en local funciona laravel con jetstream perfectamente. Pero al subirlo al servidor, me carga la vista de welcome pero no register o login. Me dice que la página no existe. error 404.

He encontrado este tema en stackOverflow en inglés... pero... no sé muy bien qué hacer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024457/unable-to-get-the-login-register-pages-with-laravel-8s-jetstream-on-apache

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema en linux y lo resolví de la siguiente manera: me dirigí al archivo etc/apache2/apache2.conf en el cambie las siguientes directrices que te muestro a continuación.

por defecto vienen de la siguiente manera

---

Directory

```
-Options FollowSymLinks
-AllowOverride none
-Require all denied
```

Directory

Directory /usr/share

```
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
```

Directory

Directory /var/www/

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
```

Directory

Las misma las cambie de esta forma

Directory

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all denied
```

Directory

Directory /usr/share

```
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Directory

Directory /var/www/

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Directory

Espero pueda ayudarte saludos.